# Set canvas object in motion using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I am beginning my study in motion, using requestAnimationFrame. I wanted to put a circle on the canvas and then set that circle into motion with a click of a button. I have achieved it, accidentally, with the following code. But I don’t get it. What I was expecting to see with this code was a circle painted on the canvas, then another circle painted on top of that circle when the button was pressed. The first circle would remain on the screen, in stationary position, while the other circle went into motion.  Again, I have accidentally achieved what I was going for, but I don’t want to build off this because it seems so wrong. What do I need to do to correct my code so that the circle appears on screen, then is set in motion with the button click?

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Creates a ball in location (but why does it disappear?) 
        c.beginPath(); 
        c.lineWidth = 5; 
        c.arc(145, 100, 75, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        c.stroke();

    var y = 100; 

    function ballDrop(){
        requestAnimationFrame(ballDrop);
        c.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 800);
        // Create Ball
        c.beginPath();
        c.lineWidth = 5;
        c.arc(145, y, 75, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        c.stroke();     
        y += 1;
    }       
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code performs as expected because:
1. You draw an initial circle on the canvas
2. You click a button which executes `ballDrop`
3. Within `ballDrop` you clear the context draw area, which removes all previous paints. This is why your original circle is gone.

A few notes:
* You don't need to keep setting `lineWidth` unless you plan on changing it for that `context`
* You should move `requestAnimationFrame` to the end of your function. This is mostly for clarity, as `requestAnimationFrame` is asynchronous (like `setTimeout`) so functionality won't really be affected.

**Example** https://jsfiddle.net/m503wa4g/6/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <button onclick="ballDrop()">Drop</button>

  <script>
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Creates a ball in location (but why does it disappear?) 
    c.beginPath(); 
    c.lineWidth = 5; 
    c.arc(145, 100, 75, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    c.stroke();

    var y = 100; 

    function ballDrop() {
      c.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 800);
      // Create Ball
      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(145, y, 75, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      c.stroke();     
      y += 1;

      requestAnimationFrame(ballDrop);
    }       

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ballDrop(){
    // start the animation that runs forever
    requestAnimationFrame(ballDrop);
    // clear the canvas so nothing is on the canvas
    // this is why the circle disappears
    c.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 800);
    // Create first Ball again so it doesn't disappear
    c.beginPath(); 
    c.lineWidth = 5; 
    c.arc(145, 100, 75, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    c.stroke();
    // Create Dropping Ball that is 1 pixel down (y+=1)
    c.beginPath();
    c.lineWidth = 5;
    c.arc(145, y, 75, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    c.stroke();
    y += 1;
}
```